# css how to make the button in the middle of this code

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple html form.

check the image please

[image]

I want the save button to but in the middle vertically

Sorry I couldn't do that, maybe you can help me.

This is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pYww5/

The code of the button is

```
.dark-matter .button {
    background: #FFF;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #333;
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Uuh, centering stuff with CSS – that has truly never been asked before …

Comment: @CBroe I wish some could help

Comment: In the middle vertically..... Between what? Vertical how? I could see `in the middle horizontally`, but I don't understand vertically. The entire form stacks vertically, there's no white space anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dark-matter .button {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  left: 28%;    
}
```